# What's wrong with my rackup file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, unicorn

When i attempt to start my unicorn server I've got the next stack trace:
Can't understand what's wrong with rackup file? Why it is not readable?

```
sites@bck:~/fatfreecrm$ /home/sites/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fatfreecrm/bin/unicorn_rails -E -D production -c /home/sites/fatfreecrm/config/unicorn.rb
/home/sites/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fatfreecrm/gems/unicorn-3.7.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:600:in `parse_rackup_file': rackup file (production) not readable (ArgumentError)
    from /home/sites/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fatfreecrm/gems/unicorn-3.7.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:74:in `reload'
    from /home/sites/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fatfreecrm/gems/unicorn-3.7.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:65:in `initialize'
    from /home/sites/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fatfreecrm/gems/unicorn-3.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:102:in `new'
    from /home/sites/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fatfreecrm/gems/unicorn-3.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:102:in `initialize'
    from /home/sites/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fatfreecrm/gems/unicorn-3.7.0/lib/unicorn.rb:30:in `new'
    from /home/sites/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fatfreecrm/gems/unicorn-3.7.0/lib/unicorn.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/sites/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fatfreecrm/gems/unicorn-3.7.0/bin/unicorn_rails:208:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sites/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fatfreecrm/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in `load'
    from /home/sites/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fatfreecrm/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the order of your arguments. Try to switch `-E` and `-D`.