# Heroku iOS Getting Started Issues

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, heroku, osx-mavericks

So I'm trying to build the Heroku iOS Getting Started app that builds a table view with a couple entries, named sushis. I'm trying to do this on Mac OSX 10.9.2, using Ruby 1.9.2 (as specified in the guide) installed through rvm. I have gone through and done bundle install for the gemfile that was in the guide as well as several others, and always had dependency issues.

With the gemfile from the guide (with a different source):

> source "https://rubygems.org"
>
> gem 'sinatra'
>
> gem 'unicorn'
>
> gem 'json'

I use the Procfile from the guide, and no config.ru file.

The link for the guide is:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-ios-development-sinatra-cedar

The error I am getting is:

```
foreman start
13:01:30 web.1  | started with pid 18498
13:01:31 web.1  | /Users/USERNAMEHERE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/unicorn-         4.8.2/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:659:in `parse_rackup_file': rackup file (config.ru) not readable (ArgumentError)
13:01:31 web.1  |   from /Users/USERNAMEHERE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:77:in `reload'
13:01:31 web.1  |   from /Users/USERNAMEHERE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:68:in `initialize'
13:01:31 web.1  |   from /Users/USERNAMEHERE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `new'
13:01:31 web.1  |   from /Users/USERNAMEHERE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `initialize'
13:01:31 web.1  |   from /Users/USERNAMEHERE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `new'
13:01:31 web.1  |   from /Users/USERNAMEHERE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
13:01:31 web.1  |   from /Users/USERNAMEHERE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
13:01:31 web.1  |   from /Users/USERNAMEHERE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
13:01:31 web.1  |   from /Users/USERNAMEHERE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
13:01:31 web.1  |   from /Users/USERNAMEHERE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
13:01:31 web.1  | exited with code 1
13:01:31 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong, as I have everything that they asked for in the guide.

Thanks

EDIT:
I now added the config.ru file:

```
require './api'

run API
```

And now I when I execute 'foreman run' it runs forever. What is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems the ordering of arguments to start the server is incorrect. There are multiple answers here

[`parse_rackup_file': rackup file (config.ru) not readable (ArgumentError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322730/parse-rackup-file-rackup-file-config-ru-not-readable-argumenterror)

and here

[What's wrong with my rackup file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451085/whats-wrong-with-my-rackup-file)